# PHP dropdown with last 60 days of dates (currently in ASP.NET) :-S

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a date array that I have used for an ASP.NET project, I'm just struggling to get this into PHP world.

It contains one `<select id="recordDate"></select>` with the last 60 days in it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
List<ListItem> dateItems = new List<ListItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i);
    dateItems.Add(new ListItem(date.ToString("ddd, dd/MM/yyyy"), date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
}
recordDate.DataValueField = "Value";
recordDate.DataTextField = "Text";
recordDate.DataSource = dateItems;
recordDate.DataBind();
recordDate.Items[0].Selected = true;
recordDate.Items[0].Text = ("Today");// (" + recordDate.Items[0].Text +")");
recordDate.Items[1].Text = ("Yesterday"); // (" + recordDate.Items[1].Text + ")");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can do this to get previous 60 days from today:

```
<select id="recordDate">
    <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) {
            echo "<option>".date("d-m-Y", strtotime('-'. $i .' days'))."</option>";
        }
    ?>

    </select>
```

And for any custom date you can do this:

```
<select>
    <?php
        $date ="09-09-2017"; // Your custom date
        for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) {
            echo "<option>".date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date.'-'. $i .' days'))."</option>";
        }
    ?>

    </select>
```

Comment: @cloudseeker Thanks